# A question related to cyclic extension and simple extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

The following question was asked in mid term exam of field theory ( Exam has concluded and I was unable to solve it. I tried it today again and failed to solve it. So, I need help with this.

> If F is a cyclic extension of K of degree $p^n$ (p prime) and L is an intermediate
> field such that F = L(u) and L is cyclic over K of degree $p^{n-1}$, then F= K(u).

It can be easily deduced that [L(u): L] =p.  I have read some results in cyclic extension from Hungerford's Algebra but I am not able move foreward in this case and need help.

Thank you !

Comment: Try to use Galois theory to give a complete list of all subextensions of $F$, and deduce that an element $u$ generates $F$ over $K$ if and only if it is not in $L$.

Comment: Please try to list the subgroups of a cyclic group of order $p^n$. Order of such a subgroup is a divisor of $p^n$ so your task is essentially is based on using the divisors of $p^n$. Then use Galois correspondence to list the subfields of $F$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Gal(F/K)=<\sigma>$ and $Gal(F/L)=<\sigma^{p^{n-1}}>$. It equals to prove $Gal(F/K(u))=\{id\}$, which we can supposed to be $\{\sigma^{p^i}\}$ with $i<n$, then u is fixed by $\sigma^{p^i}$, and it’s fixed by $\sigma^{p^{n-1}}$, causing a contradiction.

Comment: why and how you assumed  Gal(F/L)to be $< {\sigma}^{p^n -1}>$.

Comment: The structure of a cyclic group is quite clear. It’s subgroup is also cyclic and there is only one subgroup whose order is p.

Comment: sorry to say  but I am still not able to understand it.

Comment: Can you please reply to my above comment?

Comment: Do you understand that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic? Do you understand that if $d$ divides $n$ then a cyclic group of order $n$ has exactly one subgroup of order $d$?

Comment: @No-One: I think you should refer your textbook and study theorems related to cyclic groups. The properties mentioned by Gerry Myerson are quite standard and should be available in your textbook.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I already know these results which Gerry Myerson mentioned

Comment: @No-One Then you are done. In a cyclic group there is at most one subgroup of any given order. By the fundamental theorem, there's at most one intermediate field of any given degree.

Comment: @No-One: you should understand that any subgroup of $\text{Gal} (F/K) $ is cyclic and must be generated by some element like $\sigma^{p^i} $. Why? Remember if $G$ is cyclic of order $m$ with generator $a$ then any subgroup of $G$ is also cyclic and the generator must be of the form $a^k$ where $k $ divides $m$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Got it. But why is $i = p^{n-1}$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you please reply to my comment above?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Can you please elaborate I am not getting it. I shall be really thankful.